# Why Doctrine does not save entity when multiple set to false?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have the entity:

```
<?php

namespace BW\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PostCustomField
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post_custom_field")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BW\BlogBundle\Entity\PostCustomFieldRepository")
 */
class PostCustomField
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty", inversedBy="postCustomFields")
     */
    private $customFieldProperties;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customFieldProperties = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Add customFieldProperties
     *
     * @param \BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty $customFieldProperties
     * @return PostCustomField
     */
    public function addCustomFieldProperty(\BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty $customFieldProperties)
    {
        $this->customFieldProperties[] = $customFieldProperties;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove customFieldProperties
     *
     * @param \BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty $customFieldProperties
     */
    public function removeCustomFieldProperty(\BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty $customFieldProperties)
    {
        $this->customFieldProperties->removeElement($customFieldProperties);
    }

    /**
     * Get customFieldProperties
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCustomFieldProperties()
    {
        return $this->customFieldProperties;
    }
```

and have form type:

```
<?php

namespace BW\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PostCustomFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('customFieldProperties', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'BW\BlogBundle\Entity\CustomFieldProperty',
            'property' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
```

And it work fine with checkboxes, but when I try to use radio buttons (set `'multiple' => false,`) - it's render them fine, but when I check it and try to save entity to DB - I have an error:

```
Neither the property "customFieldProperties" nor one of the methods 
"addCustomFieldProperty()"/"removeCustomFieldProperty()", "setCustomFieldProperties()", 
"customFieldProperties()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class 
"BW\BlogBundle\Entity\PostCustomField".
```

Why Doctrine does not save entity with `'multiple' => false`?

P.S. Symfony Standart Edition v2.5.0

Comment: I think there is a problem with `ManyToMany` relation, isn't it? But I need `ManyToMany` relation on this property.

Comment: Do you have getters/setters for `customFieldProperties` property in the entity?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I has getter, instead setter I has add method like in my example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my own built entity and found a possible solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023284/2633720).

Based on your code you should add the function:

```
public function setCustomFieldProperties($customFieldProperties) 
{
    if (!is_array($customFieldProperties)) {
        $customFieldProperties= array($customFieldProperties);
    }
    $this->customFieldProperties= $customFieldProperties;
}
```

This did the trick for me. Indeed it seems to be a problem with the `ManyToMany` relation: by setting the `multiple` value to `false` in your `formBuilder`, it appears that we aren't dealing with Array(Collections) anymore (which you are expecting) and you have to convert it into an array.

By the way: your function `addCustomFieldProperty` will not be used anymore in that case.

I think it's better to avoid the `ManyToMany` relation if possible, but in my case I had to keep the option open to allow multiple entities for later extensions.